# What should my connection string be when connecting from Cloud Run to Cloud Sql

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am trying to connect from a Google Cloud Run instance running a java app, to a Google Cloud SQL instance.

I can not find an example anywhere on the google cloud sql docs on what exactly my mysql jdbc connection string should be.

Does anyone actually know this information?

Comment: Do you une the Cloud SQL connexion proposed in the Cloud Run product?

Answer (score 0):

I could find this example but is for cloud run fully managed, although they post the string structure in the code as:

```
// Configure which instance and what database user to connect with.
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
config.setUsername(DB_USER); // e.g. "root", "postgres"
config.setPassword(DB_PASS); // e.g. "my-password"

// For Java users, the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory can provide authenticated connections.
// See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory for details.
config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
```

You can find the whole documentation file at [this link.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#java)